# read a entire line in a binary file which consists of multiple lines in python

Tags: python, cryptography, byte, file-read

For example:
in a binary file consists multiple lines of data
xf4\x97V7\xc6e\xf6\xe7mS\xa2\x9ag5\x97\xc5.\x85\xc5\xc4
m4\x1b0\x93\x86\nM-RD\x82@sO\xe5wNb\x1b\xd6\x85\xb4\xd8\x0
\x97V7\xc6e\xf6\xe7mx\e5wNb\x1b\xd6\x85\xb4\xd8\x0

But i need to read data line by line for some process.
Can anyone help me in this logic ?

```
with open('/private].txt', 'rb') as t:
Ciphertext = t.read()
it reads all the data but i need one line of data.
Tried chunking factor also, since this lines change dynamically having trouble in that also.
```

Comment: if the file really is binary - how would you know where "one line ends" ?

Comment: when writing in file, if we use write function of a variable which is modified into bytes its writing in a single line for eg: write(X)
write(Y)
this writes in separate lines

Answer (score 0):

You can read the binary file in chunks:

**test.py:**

```
CHUNK = 8


def main():
    offset = 0

    with open("tmp.bin", "rb") as f:
        while chunk := f.read(CHUNK):
            print(f"{offset:08x}  {chunk.hex(' ', 1)}")
            offset += len(chunk)

        print(f"{offset:08x}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
00000000  51 c5 78 65 d6 5e 8a 11
00000008  0e 5f eb 3e fd de 89 3b
00000010  11 87 19 93 ca ee d0 bc
00000018  bc fb db 74 54 1a b0 b3
00000020  3e 30 7c 1f 86 ae 0e bb
00000028  46 55 2f c8 fd e6 8c 59
00000030  4d 14 15 a8 2c 71 dc 9e
00000038  27 f4 5d 0f af d7 72 48
00000040  86 db 92 16 df dd 56 cc
00000048  ce 3b 09 35 4a e4 8c 7e
00000050  79 9f 67 9a cb b0 ee 9e
00000058  bf 70 8b da 52 43 1b e7
00000060  fc 05 d0 59
00000064
```

If you really want to look for a new line character in a binary file then you can just iterate over a file object but if there is none, it will return the whole file content:

**test.py:**

```
import io
import os


SIZE = 1024


def main():
    buf = io.BytesIO(os.urandom(SIZE))

    with buf as f:
        for idx, line in enumerate(f):
            print(f"Line number: {idx} size: {len(line)}")

        print(f"# Total size: {len(buf.getvalue())}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
Line number: 0 size: 648
Line number: 1 size: 251
Line number: 2 size: 125
# Total size: 1024
$ python so.py
Line number: 0 size: 102
Line number: 1 size: 157
Line number: 2 size: 27
Line number: 3 size: 173
Line number: 4 size: 203
Line number: 5 size: 157
Line number: 6 size: 205
# Total size: 1024
```